# Gradle Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-appcompat, build.gradle

please i am trying to run an a simple login and registration app on my device. The java and xml files are fine but when i run it, i get this gradle error.
The tutorial i am following doesn't use a gradle system. It has this included in the manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Could this be the cause?

gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.stephen.logintest"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

Error Message:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42211Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 30.608 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException:
Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/annotation/AnimRes;
```

This kind of issue happens when you are using the same library with different version.

In your case check in your libs folder if some library is using the *support-annotations* library. In your dependency you are using *appcompat v21.1.1* which uses *support-annotations v.21.1.1*

Also.It is not important for this issue.

You don't need it in your Manifest.

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

These values are overrided by gradle, where you are using different values:

```
 defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
```

Comment: @StephenOkwechime mark the answer if it resolves your issue. It can help other users.